# Can you inject in produced object in CDI?

Tags: dependency-injection, cdi, weld

Suppose I have,

```
public class Ctrl{
        @Named @Produces public My getMy(){ return new My(); }
```

I can use EL expressions with `my` in it. So that's OK.

But in the `My` type itself, I cannot inject, for example,

```
public class My
    @Inject @Random private int randomNumber;
```

The `randomNumber` field in `my` above is `null`.

So my question is: Can you indeed not inject in a produced object, or am I doing something wrong?

Comment: I am also curious though, why can't you just annotate `My` with `@Named`?

Comment: @JohnAment, I know, but I wanted to see if this also works.

Comment: Ok, then I think either of the options I proposed should work for you.

Answer (score 3):

Since you manually instantiate your `My` class, it will not have dependencies inject.  That is correct.

There are ways around this though.  If you're using DeltaSpike, you can use `BeanProvider.injectFields` to populate the injection points of your bean before returning it.

If you're not using DeltaSpike, have a peak at the code to see what you can do to port the change ( https://github.com/apache/deltaspike/blob/master/deltaspike/core/api/src/main/java/org/apache/deltaspike/core/api/provider/BeanProvider.java#L395 ) :

```
BeanManager beanManager = ....; //however you get your bean manager.
CreationalContext creationalContext = beanManager.createCreationalContext(null);
AnnotatedType annotatedType = beanManager.createAnnotatedType(instance.getClass());
InjectionTarget injectionTarget = beanManager.createInjectionTarget(annotatedType);
injectionTarget.inject(instance, creationalContext);
```